# How do I convince cpanminus to install modules in lib/ instead of lib/perl5?

Tags: perl, configuration, installation, cpan, cpanm

I'm installing a bunch of modules listed in a `cpanfile` into a self-contained directory:

```
 cpanm -L bundle --quiet --notest --self-contained --with-recommends --installdeps .
```

Afterward, all the modules are in `bundle/lib/perl5`. Which is almost exactly what I want. Is there an incantation to feed `cpanm` — or an environment variable to set — to get `cpanm` to tell the installer to put the files in `bundle/lib`, instead? I assume I'd need to do something to convince ExtUtils::MakeMaker and Module::Build to append a different value to the `install_base`, but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: It sounds like you have `local::lib` installed to `bundle/lib/perl5`?

Comment: I'm passing `-L bundle`, which builds things as if local::lib is set to `bundle`. It installs modules in `bundle/lib/perl5`, I think, because `$Config{installstyle}` is set to `lib/perl5` and not `lib` — and that's true regardless of what local::lib is set to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trolling through the [Module::Build source](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Module-Build/), it [looks like it's not possible](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Module-Build/blob/master/lib/Module/Build/Base.pm#L297) to install modules without the `perl5` part of the directory — at least not when using `install_base` (which cpanm's `--self-contained` implies). Judging from the comment, it appears that the decision was made to be consistent about always installing in `lib/perl5` when using `install_base`, so as to keep things as predictable as possible. It looks like [MakeMaker has it hard-coded](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/blob/master/lib/ExtUtils/MM_Any.pm#L2195), too.